# Rails 4: Partial can't use javascript after being rendered (with ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm doing an Ajax request with CoffeeScript and then rendering a partial from my controller, but then after that the partial has been rendered it can't use the Javascript I had previously.

Example:

At the end my action of my `home_controller` I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render partial: 'frame' }
end
```

In my `home.js.coffee`:

```
$('#plouf').click -> 
  alert('test')
```

Then in my partial `_frame.html.erb` (in the home folder of the views folder)

```
<span id="plouf">test<span>
```

If I click on this span, nothing happens...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

But if I add this line in my partial it works, but I know it's ugly since I already did it in my `application.html.erb`

Am I missing something, or is it normal that partial can't use any previous Javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partials are compiled into the view before javascript is run by the browser.

What you need is

```
$(document).on 'click', '#plouf', ->
  alert('test')
```

This binds the event to the document, so when turbolinks or ajax reloads the HTML, your event handler is still active.

Comment: Thanks! I understand better now, but I had to rewrite as: `$(document).on('click', '#plouf', ( -> alert('test')))`

Comment: Please fix the commas, should be: `$(document).on 'click', '#plouf', ->`

Comment: @d_rail better? You can always suggest an edit too :)

Comment: what if I want to apply some js on render, not on particular event like click or change e.g. some datatable property.